# Laravel combine two route to have simple url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

in laravel i have this routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/showContent/{content}', 'HomeController@showContent');
```

first is for show main page and secode is for show single post, now i'm trying to combine them for one route as:

```
Route::get('/{content?}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

if `content` is not null, web application must be show single post otherwise show home page like with this controller

```
public function index($slug)
{
    if ($slug != null) {
        $this->showContent($slug);
    } else {
        return view('layouts.frontend.content');
    }
}
```

but i get error for `index` function, how can i resolve that?

Comment: Share what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the default value of `$slug` to `null` in your method signature like so:

```
public function index($slug = null)
{
    if ($slug != null) {
        $this->showContent($slug);
    } else {
        return view('layouts.frontend.content');
    }
}
```

This allows the parameter to be optional on the controller side, since the Laravel Router will call the controller action method without any parameters when accessig the root `/`.

> You should keep in mind that defining a route as `/{parameter?}` is essentially a catch all, meaning **any URL** that does not match another route definition or is not a physical file on disk will be a match to this route (e.g. /foo, /bar, etc.), so take that into consideration when choosing this approach, as you'll always be executing the `showContent()` part for unmatched URLs.

Comment: Good explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can assign `null` as default in function param

```
  public function index($slug=null)
  {
     if (!$slug) {
         return view('layouts.frontend.content');
     }
     $this->showContent($slug);
  }
```